# How can I efficiently find out what certs I need to add to my Java keystore?

Tags: java, ssl

PKIX path building failed; We've all seen it before.  In a complex environment there can be many certs missing.  Is there a simple way to determine which urls are failing to reduce the amount of guess & check work on the keystore?

For a little more context, I did find the class making the call and attempt to do some logging, but the url being requested is pretty obfuscated.  Is it possible to get javax.net.ssl to give more information about the failed request?

Comment: Try passing `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` into the execution.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thank you!  Very helpful.  Output is tough but it did help me find the url to get certificate for.  If you add as the answer i'll put it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to see thorough and detailed output about the certificate store, you can pass the debug SSL flag into the program’s execution arguments.

`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`

More info can be found on the official Oracle documentation page: *“[Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)”*